# Moving local data out of function

Tags: rust, reference, ownership

I'm pretty new to Rust and struggling with the concepts of ownership.
In this example, I'm using [SIMD Json for Rust](https://crates.io/crates/simd-json/) library to parse JSON. It has a concept of parsing "borrowed values" - JSON objects referencing the original JSON bytes.

To make this example self-sufficient, let's use these signatures:

```rust
// Emulating simd_json::BorrowedValue
pub enum BorrowedValue<'value> {
    SomeEnumOption(&'value str)
}

// Emulating simd_json::to_borrowed_value parsing function
pub fn to_value(buf: &mut [u8]) -> Result<BorrowedValue, String> {
    todo!()
}
```

Now I want to make a self-sufficient struct that would carry both the original JSON as well as the parsed structue:

```rust
pub struct ParsedJson<'value> {
    file_content: Vec<u8>,
    pub parsed: BorrowedValue<'value>,
}
```

However, I fail to create such struct:

```rust
fn transform<'value>(mut buf: Vec<u8>) -> Result<ParsedJson<'value>, String> {
    let mut result = ParsedJson {
        file_content: buf,
        parsed: BorrowedValue::SomeEnumOption("nothing here yet"),
    };

    match to_value(&mut result.file_content) {
        Ok(bw) => {
            result.parsed = bw;
            Ok(result)
        }
        Err(e) => Err(e)
    }
}
```

This results in an error:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local data `result.file_content`
  --> src/json.rs:39:13
   |
36 |     match to_value(&mut result.file_content) {
   |                    ------------------------ `result.file_content` is borrowed here
...
39 |             Ok(result)
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

Why is `result.file_content` considered local data? I expected I could move it out.

To add to the confusion, it seems to not be considered a local data anymore if I don't pass a mutable reference to `to_value`:

```rust
fn transform<'value>(mut buf: Vec<u8>) -> Result<ParsedJson<'value>, String> {
    let mut result = ParsedJson {
        file_content: buf,
        parsed: BorrowedValue::SomeEnumOption("nothing here yet"),
    };

    Ok(result) // This compiles just fine!
}
```

What is the problem and what is the proper way to implement that? I'm completely lost here, any pointers would be appreciated.